# What is the problem with groupTableViewBackgroundColor on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, background-color, uicolor

My background color is white! Why?
Just start an new View-based app for iPad and set background color in viewDidLoad.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
}
```

What is wrong. If I set it to redColor it works. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`groupTableViewBackgroundColor` on the iPad (or at least on an iPad with iOS 4.2) is the same as `clearColor`, rather than the pattern used on the iPhone. You can create a "color" with your own background pattern using UIColor's `colorWithPatternImage:` method.

Answer (score 0):

groupTableViewBackgroundColor does not work for iPad. It is iPhone only. Instead, you can use

```
UIColor *clr = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.875 green:0.88 blue:0.91 alpha:1];
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:clr];
```